# Crystal radio question

Tags: radio, receiver

I plan on trying to make some crystal radio sets. The only place I can do this is on the second story, do I have to add anything to the wire coming up from the ground because I'm on the second story?

Comment: which wire? the antenna? Big question! We don't know your design!

Comment: Sorry but I have no clue as to what you are asking... Please clarify your question. Maybe post a schematic, or describe in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: are you using a loop antenna or a long wire antenna?

Comment: What do you plan to use for antenna and earth?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a ferrite loopstick antenna in a broadcast-AM (MF) crystal radio, then no external wires are needed for an antenna or ground.  (I built a few when I was a kid, and used them from a second story).

If you use an air coil instead of a ferrite rod for your tuning inductor, then a couple wires, with one for a long wire antenna, and perhaps one for a counterpose, might be necessary (depending on station signal strengths). But both can be above ground.

Answer (score 0):

Should the wire coming up from the ground be the earth wire, then nothing is required to be added to that.

You'll now only need to connect an antenna and earth to your crystal radio.